# Sin^2(x) Boundaries (Very Basic Question)

Tags: functions, inequality

I'm trying to find the boundaries of $Sin^2(x)$.

This is my procedure:

For any $\pi/2\le x\le 3\pi/2$

I apply the function $sin(x)$ which for that interval it would be decreasing. So,

$1 \ge sin(x) \ge -1$

$-1 \le sin(x) \le 1$

I apply the function $x^2$ which for that interval it would be increasing. So,

$1 \le sin^2(x) \le 1$

Which leads me to nothing.

[image]

Seeing the graph, what was $x=\pi/2$ would still be equal to $1$. And what was $x=3\pi/2$ would change from $-1$ to $1$. So I see that in order to know that the boundaries of $sin^2(x)$ are $[0;1]$ I would have to pick $\pi/2\le x\le \pi$ for example. And only then, I could come to notice of that. Still, I don't know if it is my rusty perspective of inequalities which is messing with me, but I don't understand why choosing the first boundaries, it then doesn't inform me that the function $sin^2(x)$ could in fact become any value between $0$ and $1$. Dumb question. Maybe I'm messing up something in the procedure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any real $\;a,x\;,\;\;a\ge o\;$ , we have that

$$-a\le x\le a\iff |x|\le a\implies 0\le x^2\le a^2$$

In your case:

$$-1\le \sin x\le 1\implies 0\le \sin^2x\le 1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$f^2(x)$ is always a positive number, over the reals, hence $f^2(x) \geq 0$.

With this in mind, what are the lowest and highest attainable values in your case?